# Upgrading iOS Application

Tags: ios, objective-c, cocoa-touch, ios5, ios4

I want to upgrade my existing apps to **iOS 5.0 and above.**

I want **suggestions and detailed guide line** for main points. 
what changes I should make in my existing code to make it fully 
compatible as new iOS coding standards.

For e.g.

- Should I change all external frameworks and my custom classes 
     for making it compatible for ARC?
- I should make changes into sqlite database creation.
- Should I replace old framework of Twitter & Facebook?
- What kind of changes I should do with Graphics?

**In-short, Please provide guideline and suggestion that are important for making older app fully compatible with New iOS standards.**

> Guys thanks for providing your comments & reply for this question.
>
> By Looking at your response, I think you guys are only focusing on the
>   above given points. I want general suggestions from your experience.
>   i.e. what things we should change in info.plist, what changes should
>   be done in graphics. how we can improve app by adding automatic ARC
>   support etc ...
>
> Main thing is how we can make it compatible for different resolutions
>   of iPhone / iPad (i.e. for iPhone 5 and other devices).

If possible then please provide graphics changes guidelines with 
     resolution for new iPhone 5 Device and iPad Mini Device.

Your help / suggestions / Guidelines will be greatly appreciated!

Comment: This is my first question so i am not much aware about formatting :)

Comment: You have already mentioned in your profile, so no need of it in the question.

Comment: @Maulik Thanks for the clearing it. I will keep this in mind from my next post. If possible then please help me out with your suggestions and guidelines to improve my existing iOS apps.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Should I change all external frameworks and my custom classes for making it compatible for ARC?

It depends entirely upon you.  ARC is a compile-time feature that is meant to obviate the task of manual memory management.  It doesn't eliminate it by any stretch of the imagination, but it is miles safer than anything we as programmers could ever hope to write most of the time.  It is possible to mix ARC and non-ARC frameworks and libraries in an application.

> I should make changes into sqlite database creation.

iOS has always shipped with libSQLite3, so there is absolutely no work required for you to "upgrade" this aspect of your application.  You might consider a move to core data, if only because again, it obviates large portions of interfacing with SQLite.

> Should I replace old framework of Twitter & Facebook?

Again, it depends.  If you plan on supporting older OSes which do not come with the new iOS social features and frameworks, then I'd leave it as is.  The new API is far more limiting than accessing the actual API for each of the given social services, but it is also far easier to implement, especially for things like simple wall posts.

> What kind of changes I should do with Graphics?

Graphics files must (optimally) come in 2 flavors with an optional third format for the new iPhone: standard, retina, and stretched retina.  While opting into retina-graphics is completely optional, it is recommended that you provide high-resolution assets to provide the best user experience.  In regards to the actual graphics library (CoreGraphics), the framework handles the scaling of elements drawn to the screen.

Answer (score 0):

**- Should I change all external frameworks and my custom classes for making it compatible for ARC?**

> If your frameworks are out dated then, YES you need to update it so
>   its compatible for iOS 5 and above. For ARC, its not necessary. If you
>   don't wanted to handle memory management then you can.

**- Should I replace old framework of Twitter & Facebook?**

> YES please.

**- What kind of changes I should do with Graphics?**

> You need to change graphics for ratina display. Google about it.